# How to get values from different table and pass it to a trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures, triggers

i have 3 tables:

```
event:
---------------------
event_id | uid | date
---------------------

event_invitees
----------------------
invitees_id | event_id
---------------------- 

notification
-----------------
uid | invitees_id
-----------------
```

i have created one trigger which will insert into 'notification' table after insert on 'event_invitees'

```
delimiter |
create trigger eventNotificationTrigger after insert on event_invitees
for each row 
begin
declare id int(12);
set id = (select uid from event where event_id=new.event_id);
insert into notification (invitees_id,uid) select invitees_id,@id from event_invitees where event_id=new.event_id;
end;
|
```

But it is not able to fetch uid from the event table. So how to fetch different values from different tables and insert them to one table in trigger?

Comment: What do you mean by *not able to fetch*? Do you have an error?

Comment: not not having any error...but its inserting `0` at `uid` in `notification` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `@`

```
insert into notification (invitees_id,uid) 
select invitees_id, @id from event_invitees where ...
                    ^-------------------------------------here
```

Variables you create with `declare` won't be referenced with `@`. Only the one's you create with `set`. Example:

```
declare id int(12);
select 1 into id;
select id;

set @id = (select 1);
select @id;
```